# How to create a list of class in another class?

Tags: c#, list, class, nested

I am dealing with the following class structure:

```
 internal class C1
{
    private static readonly int iMinVal = 1;
    private static readonly int iMaxVal = 100;
    public readonly int Number;

    public C1(int iNum)
    {
        if (iNum < iMinVal || iNum > iMaxVal)
            throw new OverflowException();
        this.Number = iNum;
    }
}

internal partial class C2
{
    public readonly List<C1> Series = new List<C1>(10);

    public C2(List<int> lNumbers)
    {
        lNumbers.Sort();

        try
        {
            Series[0] = new C1(lNumbers[0]);
            Series[1] = new C1(lNumbers[1]);
            Series[2] = new C1(lNumbers[2]);
            Series[3] = new C1(lNumbers[3]);
            Series[4] = new C1(lNumbers[4]);
            Series[5] = new C1(lNumbers[5]);
            Series[6] = new C1(lNumbers[6]);
            Series[7] = new C1(lNumbers[7]);
            Series[8] = new C1(lNumbers[8]);
            Series[9] = new C1(lNumbers[9]);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("M1!","M2");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I try to use these two classes in the following way:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<C2> lRes = new List<C2>(5);
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++)
        {
            List<int> lNumbers = new List<int> {6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 10, 8, 7, 9};
            lRes[iRow] = new C2(lNumbers);
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. The **error message** says:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I will be very appreciated if anybody could help me to find my mistake.

Comment: `List<C2> lRes = new List<C1>(5);` does this even compile ? there is no inheritance between `C1` and `C2`

Comment: `new C1(lNumbers);` <-- There is no constructor that accept a `List<int>` type.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I just edit my code. These errors crept in my code since I just changed the names in my original code to simplify my code and protect the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, line

```
 public readonly List<C1> Series = new List<C1>(10);
```

means "Create list with **0** items, but *reserve* space for `10` items (in order to not reallocating memory)". 
Please, note that `Series` *doesn't have any items*, and that's why

```
 Series[0] = new C1(lNumbers[0]);
```

will throw exception (`Series[0]` *doesn't exist* since `0` is *out of range*). You should `Add` items, e.g. quick (and dirty) patch

```
  public C2(List<int> lNumbers) {
    lNumbers.Sort();

    try
    {
        Series.Clear();

        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[0])));
        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[1]));
        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[2]));
        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[3]));
        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[4]));
        Series.Add(new C1(lNumbers[5]));
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("M1!","M2");
        throw;
    }
}
```

a better approach is *Linq*:

```
// IEnumerable<int> - let's generalize: what if we want to pass an array?
public C2(IEnumerable<int> lNumbers) {
  // public method arguments validation
  if (null == lNumbers)  
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lNumbers));

  try {
    Series = lNumbers
      .OrderBy(item => item) 
      //.Take(10) // uncomment, if you want to take just top 10 items, not more
      .Select(item => new C1(item))
      .ToList();
  }
  catch (OverflowException) {
    MessageBox.Show("M1!","M2");
    throw;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Series is a list of C1 items, i would use Series.Add() instead on Series[0],[1] etc, or youre basically using a list as if it was an array

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you are doing `Row < 5` but there are 6 of these lines `Series[0] = new C1(lNumbers[0]);`

So is the `Series[5] = new C1(lNumbers[5]);` outside the index causing that error?

EDIT: Also this line is incorrect in OP.

```
List<**C2**> lRes = new List<**C1**>(5);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just edited the code. These errors crept in my code since I changed the names. Would you kindly have another look on edited code, please?

Answer (score 1):

You code is confusing (at least for me).
But the first thing I would change is the way you "add" elements to your list.
You should use the Add method to add elements to your list.
Also there is no reason to create a new List lNumbers each for iteraction.

Answer (score 1):

The *C1* class will store an integer number, no issue on that.

The *C2* class will store a *List* of *C1* objects. It is instantiated on declaration, giving it the size of 10. Be careful: it is still empty, no matter the size you set.

So, the dirty filling on *C2* constructor, will correctly raise the exception. See the working code:

```
Series.Add(new C1(lnumber[0]));
...
Series.Add(new C1(lnumber[9]));
```

As suggested by Dmitry, it would be much better to use the *Linq* approach.

On *btn_Click* method, you are making the same mistake. The *lRes* List is correctly initialized and sized, but still empty. So, you have to apply the same fix seen before:

```
lRes.Add(new C2(lNumbers);
```